# How to dispatch an action after completing another dispatch? React-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an api call which returns a JWT token,on receving the api call a dispatch is called.I have another Api call that send to another domain. The second api needs the Jwt token from the first api call.But the second api is not getting the JWT token. it says its an [object]. While calling a third api after a moment it gets the jwt token.I need to perform the dispatch in syncronous manner, First complete the first api call then the second api call

Redux-thunk might be the answer, but i don't know the implemenation

Comment: We need to know what you have tried till now so that we could guide further or provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass an anonymous function in 1st api call and dispatch it in the 1st api success and pass JWT token as a argument. In this anonymous action you can call another APIs.